# copy data of listbox to sheet without vba

Tags: excel

How can I send all items from the listbox table to cell in excel? without vba.

For example, I made a table and I want to see how to transfer the list box to other cells without using vba and duplicates.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zh6hy.png)

I think it should be simple, but I have no idea how to copy the listbox data to another cell or should I use vba?

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/unique-function-c5ab87fd-30a3-4ce9-9d1a-40204fb85e1e